# Paging received information from table in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I page info that is received from mysql table..
I want to show on **every** page **4 rows**
I have this code :

```
<?php
    include_once "config.php";
    $sql_select_product = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY date DESC;";
    $result_select_product = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_select_product);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_select_product) > 0) {
        while ($row_select_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select_product)) {
            echo "
    <div class='col-6 col-sm-3' style='margin-bottom: 20px;'>
        <img width='250' height='250' src='on_login_pages/uploads/$row_select_product[img]'/>
        <div class='des'>
            <div class='price\">$row_select_product[price]</div>
            <div class='name\">$row_select_product[name]</div>
            <div class=''>$row_select_product[weight]</div>
            <div class=''>$row_select_product[work_type]</div>
        </div>
    </div>";
        }
    }
    $connection->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `servername/path/script_name.php?page=[page_number]`the script will return only 4 elements of the query.

```
<?php
$page_number = fiter_input(INPUT_GET,'page',FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,1,1);
$rows_per_page = 4;
$offset = ($page_number - 1) * $rows_per_page;
include_once "config.php";
$sql_select_product = sprintf("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT %d OFFSET %d;",
  $rows_per_page,$offset);
$result_select_product = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_select_product);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_select_product) > 0) {
  while ($row_select_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_select_product)) {
    echo "
<div class='col-6 col-sm-3' style='margin-bottom: 20px;'>
    <img width='250' height='250' src='on_login_pages/uploads/$row_select_product[img]'/>
    <div class='des'>
        <div class='price\">$row_select_product[price]</div>
        <div class='name\">$row_select_product[name]</div>
        <div class=''>$row_select_product[weight]</div>
        <div class=''>$row_select_product[work_type]</div>
    </div>
</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit` in your query. Something like this:

```
select * from table_name order by column_name asc limit $offset,$startfrom;
```